# Swipes not being detected (Swift/iOS9)

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

In my `viewDidLoad`:

```
let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("leftSwiped"))
        swipeLeft.direction = .Left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft
```

### )

```
func leftSwiped()
    {
        print("here")
    }
```

"here" is never printed. I tried looking at other guides, but the core of the code is the same that I have. I don't think I'm supposed to subclass anything. Could I get some help on this?

Comment: Hm, this code works fine for me. Are you swiping the correct direction when you test it?

Comment: oh how embarrassing! I kept thinking since the view was going to popout on the left that I'm swiping left xD

Answer (score 0):

> let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:
>   Selector("leftSwiped"))

You missing "**:**" after name function "**leftSwiped**"

Try source code:

```
let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("leftSwiped:"))

        swipeLeft.direction = .Left

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
```